# Handling System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Given this code:

```
readFile = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open);
streamReader = new StreamReader(readFile);

dsSheet = new DataSet();
dsSheet.Tables.Add(sValidNumbersLibrary);
dsSheet.Tables[sValidNumbersLibrary].Columns.Add("Numbers");
dt50Records = dsSheet.Tables[sValidNumbersLibrary].Clone();

String sLine = string.Empty;
sLine = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
// The next line fails with System.OutOfMemoryException:
sLine = (sLine.Contains(",")) ? sLine.Replace(",", "\r\n") : sLine;
sLine = sLine.Replace("\r\n", ",");
```

How should I handle this `System.OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: With a try catch?  Seriously though, just read it in chunks.  Don't put it all in memory at once.

Comment: Which like causes the exception? The ReadToEnd?

Comment: getting error on this line sLine = (sLine.Contains(",")) ? sLine.Replace(",", "\r\n") : sLine;

Comment: How big is `sLine` when the problem occurs?

Comment: Do not repost questions. Ask the question once, and if you're getting downvotes, fix the question, don't post it again.

Comment: I deleted the original (closed) question and cleared the close votes on this one.  There only needs to be one copy of a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you planning to do with the altered string once you're done with your manipulation?  If you are just going to write it to a file, then perhaps you should read one line at a time, perform your manipulation, then write the altered line to the file. StreamReader's readline will return everything until it encounters \r\n.  Since you are planning on replacing \r\n with ",", you can just append a comma to the string returned by readline.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.GetTempFileName()))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"YourFile"))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (line != null)
            {
                sw.Write(line + ",");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are planning on using your manipulated text throughout the rest of your code, then you can build the string with StringBuilder (replace sw.Write with sb.Append); however, using StringBuilder will not guarantee that you won't run into an OutOfMemoryException. A large string is a large string.  If there's no contiguous block of memory for your string, then you will get that OutOfMemoryException. Also, as @SteveCzetty pointed out, your calls to string.Replace() returns a copy of your string.  The larger the string, the more likely you're going to encounter the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would add

```
streamReader.Dispose();
```

after sLine = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); 
this would free some memory before you initiate the replace process.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous comments that you should read the file in chunks, but if you must read the entire chunk into memory at once:

String.Replace() is returns a *copy* of the string, so after the replace, you are using twice as much memory as before.  Try using StringBuilder.Replace() instead, or if you are really pressed for RAM, load the string into a byte array and manipulate the string inline.  (Though, since you are replacing one character with two, that poses some issues.)

I'm going to think about it and revisit this.